# FBX export modifies IK bones

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

I have made a model with armature and animated 2 actions, idle and walking, but when I export to fbx the walking animation gets weird bellow are the original blend file and the same model after exporting and importing, (I am showing in blender but I intend to use in unity, and the import in unity has the same weird animation)

Original:

[image: original]

Exported (and imported):

[image: imported]

I have this Exporting settings, (I tried without **apply transform**, without **nla strips** and with **add leaf bones**)

[image: FBX Export settings]

I have this on my scene:

[image: Scene]

The transforms of all mesh and bones:

*(not sure I should select everything but individually they are all applied with location and rotation at 0 and scale at 1)*

[image: transforms]

Just in case the affected bone transforms:

[image: bone transform]

Note: *Although I had other issue before this IK bones getting larger, I had a second armature on top, that issue I solved by deleting the NLA Tracks action stash, there was an animation there (I might have changed some settings trying to solve this issue and now is causing the new issue)*

Comment: Please share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell for sure without the file but it looks like you scales aren't locked in at 1. You should try applying the transforms in the viewport with ctrl + A and hit Apply all transforms this should be done for your armature and your mesh. Going from blender to unity or unreal can be a little tricky if this isn't done. When you do this other problems may arise you may after to do some reparenting or animating to make things right.You may have to do this with the bones that seem to be growing in size but usually doing it on the whole armature fixes the issue! Let me know if this works.
[image: Not scaled to 1]
[image: Apply all transforms]
[image: Scale set to 1]

Comment: sorry for the delay, they are all applied, I double checked and I had a slight position change but it wasn't the issue it was just some modification I did after the fact, I apply all transforms again now and its still the same.

Comment: Maybe instead of using the NLA you can try storing the animations in the action editor and importing them separately? I also notice that you're using WXYZ rotations, try switching the euler to XYZ instead. the fourth rotation gets a little wonky sometimes